# Is every instance of a spring boot application created in a cloud will have its own initialisation?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I have developed a Spring Boot Application and I am using Distributed Cache, I wrote a logic in ApplicationStartup to update the Cache values.
What if I have multiple instances (say for example - 3 instances) in my Cloud? Will every instance execute that ApplicationStartup logic and update the Cache values every time?

Comment: If you run three copies of your code, then yes, **everything** in there will run on each copy. This isn't related to Spring or even which specific cloud provider you use.

Comment: Thanks, @JoachimSauer, In that case, we have to write custom logic to avoid duplicate updates of the cache right

Comment: Maybe, it depends on many factors (among others if multiple updates are actually a problem, if it's a pull-through cache, ...).

Comment: The right pattern is to have the cache in an external service and not in your java code directly. Memorystore is a good place for that.

Comment: The challenge you are facing has been solved many times in the past. The solution you are looking for is "Distributed Lock". For example: https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/distributed-locks/

Comment: Realy Thanks for your replies. Let me tell you my use case, I have 2 components A (3 instances) and B, and Distributed Cache. And there is an observer pattern between A and B. A listens to B for changes and will update the Cache. Since there are 3 instances of A, it is being called 3 times. Hope it makes sense
cc @Ventrue